# Find $f(0),f'(0),f''(0)$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $f(x)$ has second derivative on some neighbourhood around $x=0$, and $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1+x+\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)^{1/x}=e^3$$ Find $f(0),f'(0),f''(0)$

I know $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$ must be $0$ or the limit wouldn't exist. Then after some rough calculation, I guess $f''(0)$ should be $2$. My problem is I have trouble to write the proof with strict words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the given condition we get via taking logarithm (and the fact that $\log$ function is continuous) $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\log\left(1+x+\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)=3\tag{1}$$ and by multiplying with $x$ we can see that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\log\left(1+x+\frac {f(x)} {x} \right) =0$$ Next the continuity of $\exp$ function gives us $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1+x+\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)=1$$ so that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0\tag{2}$$ Multiplication by $x$ gives us $$f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}x\cdot \frac {f(x)} {x} =0\cdot 0=0$$ and then $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {f(x) - f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0\text{ (via (2))}$$ To evaluate $f''(0)$ we need more effort. It is known that the second derivative $f''(0)$ exists and hence the limit $$f''(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{x}$$ exists. By L'Hospital's Rule we have $$f''(0)=2\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\tag{3}$$ It is now time to revisit equation $(1)$. Using the fundamental limit $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac {\log(1+t)} {t} =1$$ the equation $(1)$ can be rewritten as $$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x+\dfrac{f(x)} {x} }{x}=3$$ or $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=2$$ and by equation $(3)$ we see that $f''(0)=4$.

To sum up $$f(0)=f'(0)=0,f''(0)=4$$ As the above solution shows we don't really need the existence of second derivative $f''$ in some neighborhood of $0$ but only its existence at the point $0$.

Comment: To use the "fundamental limit" at the start don't you need to have that $f(x)/x\to 0$? You only seem to prove that later on - I am worried that this is slightly circular.

Comment: @ancientmathematician well it got messed up a bit while editing. I will fix this thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: rolled back to the previous version and you may have a look at it again.

Comment: Don't you need to know that $\lim f(x)/x$ exists before you can use "continuity of $\log$"?

Comment: @ancientmathematician: that can be handled via continuity of exponential function.

Comment: Yes, of course it can. A small suggestion to make it complete: note that in the very first line you use the continuity of $\log$. It's a real beast of an exercise!

Comment: @ancientmathematician: I have fixed that part and mentioned continuity of $\exp$ now. Thanks for your feedback which helped to fix some issues.

Answer (score 0):

First， as you see, $f(0)=f'(0)=0$. By taking logarithm, we rewrite the assumption as follows
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x+\frac{f(x)}{x})}{x}=3.$$ Then, by L'Hôpital's rule， we have
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1+x+\frac{f(x)}{x}}\left(1+\frac{f'(x)x-f(x)}{x^2}\right)=3.$$ Noting that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)/x=0$, the above limit implies that
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)x-f(x)}{x^2}=2.$$ Using L'Hôpital's rule once more, we can get
$$f''(0)=4.$$

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.  I also want to wondering how to determine $f(0)=0,f'(0)=0$ by using these rigorous words.

Comment: You are trying to use L'Hospital's Rule in reverse. This is not the right approach but it can be fixed by making suitable modification.

Answer (score 0):

We know that

$$\lim_{x\to0}(1+3x)^{1/x}=e^3,$$ so that $f(x)=2x^2$ fulifills the criterion.

We can show that $$\left(1+x+\frac{a+bx+2x^2}x\right)^{1/x}$$ diverges for any $a,b\ne0$.

Answer (score -1):

We can use  it  this to solve this problem.
first we can use this limit representation of $e^k$

$$ 
{
e^k=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{k}{n} \right)^n 
\qquad (1)
}
$$
 and changing n to 1 / x and substituting k = 3

$$ 
{
e^3=\lim_{x\to0} \left( 1+
3x \right)^{\frac{1}{x}} 
\qquad (2)
}
$$

Then using (2) we can see that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x+\frac{f(x)}{x})^\frac{1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0} \left( 1+
3x \right)^{\frac{1}{x}} $$
And afther that we see that 
$$x+\frac{f(x)}{x}=3x$$
$$\frac{f(x)}{x}=2x$$
$$f(x)=2x^2$$

Although this form of equating terms can not be used habitually, since the limit of two funcuons are equal does not mean that two functions are the same. But in this case it can be deduced from the statement that all possible functions f have the same derivative in 0, since otherwise the statement would contradict itself and have multiple solutions. Then with analyzing the derivatives of the simplest function that can be f is sufficient to extrapolate it to all the f.

So we can easily solve the problem by replacing  the zeros and  the derivatives
$$f(0)=2\cdot 0^2 =0$$
$$f'(0)=4\cdot 0 =0 $$
$$f''(0)=4$$
Thanks for reading and goodbye.

Comment: If the limit of two functions is same it does not mean that they are equal. Your answers has serious issues. - 1

Comment: You can keep it easy but not mathematically wrong. And we are not supposed to find $f$ here as the given condition does not determine $f$ uniquely. Rather we are supposed to find the derivatives of $f$ at $0$ and this can be done without knowing $f$ explicitly.

Comment: it can be easily deduced from the same statement of the problem that all the possible functions f have the same derivatives in 0. Therefore, just by evaluating one, all the possible ones are evaluated f

Comment: When you deduce that all the derivatives have the same value in that process you will actually evaluate the derivatives. So it is better that you include that deduction in your answer.

Comment: So if I include in the answer that due to the statement all the derivatives have the same value because if it were not, it would contradict itself and could have multiple soluctions, with only analyzing a possible f (the simplest) is enough to extrapolate To all the possible f, the solution could be more rigorous?  thanks for the interesting talk

Comment: Well just mentioning this statement in answer would not be enough. You will have to show why the statement is true (or show why it's falsity would imply a contradiction). If you do that you will find something similar to my answer here.